# Netty ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, io, netty

I am new to netty and I followed this [example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.html) to write a static file server using netty. But whenever the server serves a large js file. It runs into ClosedChannelException.

The following is my code where I write chunkedFile as http response.
When a large js file is being served I get closedChannelException and the raf file is also closed.

Could you help me figure out what I have done wrong here? Also, is there a simple tutorial where I get understand the basic flow of control in netty?

> ```
>      // Write the content.
>       ChannelFuture writeFuture = null;
>     try
>     {
>         long fileLength = raf.length();
>         HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(
>             HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
>         response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, fileLength);
>         Channel c = ctx.getChannel();
> ```

```
        // Write the initial line and the header.
        c.write(response);

        writeFuture = c.write(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192));
    }
    finally
    {
        raf.close();
        if (writeFuture != null)
            writeFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling raf.close() in the finally block is wrong as it may not have it written yet. In fact netty will take care to close it after the write is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Since netty writes asynchronously the close in finally block seems to be the culprit. Could you also tell me where netty takes care of closing the raf file? Is there a document or a tutorial that I can read to understand this better?

Comment: Figured out that ChunkedFile takes care of closing the raf file. Thanks!